# Complexity to get object from openstack swift

Tags: openstack, openstack-swift

What is the complexity of `Container container = account.getContainer("my-new-container");` from http://docs.ceph.com/docs/master/radosgw/swift/java/

and the complexity of `GET /v1/{account}/{container}/{object}` from https://developer.openstack.org/api-ref/object-store/index.html#get-object-content-and-metadata.

I guess it is `log(n)`, but I am not sure. I cannot find the document. Maybe I should read the Openstack swift source codes? Could someone give more details?